# formatting date from twitter response Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, twitter, zend-date

im trying to formatting the date field 'created_at' from Twitter API response with Zend_Date. I want output the date like this:

21 of July of 2009, 12:30:00 (for example)

What format is this?:

Fri Oct 23 15:47:42 +0000 2009

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the best luck just doing

```
$d = new Zend_Date(strtotime($input));
$twitter_format_out = $d->toString('EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYY');
```

Comment: You can set me as the answer then :-)

Answer (score 1):

These date are not looking a standard format. Therefore, you have to create a format with the right constants ([see them here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.selfdefinedformats)).

Your first example (21 of July of 2009, 12:30:00):

```
$format = "d ' of ' MMMM ' of ' YYYY, h:mm:ss";
```

Your second example (Fri Oct 23 15:47:42 +0000 2009):

```
$format = "EEE MMM d h:mm:ss Z YYYY";
```

This formats you can use both for importing a date

```
$date = new Zend_Date($string, $format);
```

Or for outputting

```
$date->toString($format);
```

Look in the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.html) for locale support etc.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your answer.

Twitter generate in the xml the node created_at with this date:

Fri Oct 23 15:47:42 +0000 2009

In Zend_Date Im trying 

$date = new Zend_Date('Fri Oct 23 15:47:42 +0000 2009');

and for output:

$date->toString('EEEE d MMM YYYY');

but returns:

wed 24 march 2010

what im doing wrong??

thanks